# How to connect to cassandra DB with SSL using django_cassandra_engine in Python?

Tags: python, cassandra

```
'cassandra': {

    'ENGINE': 'django_cassandra_engine',

    'NAME': '',

    'USER': config.get("database", "cassandra_user"),

    'PASSWORD': config.get("database", "cassandra_password"),

    'HOST': '',

    'connection': {

        'consistency': ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE,

        'retry_connect': True

        # + All connection options for cassandra.cluster.Cluster()

    },

    'session': {

        'default_timeout': 30,

        'default_fetch_size': 10000,

        'retry_connect' : True
    }
}
```

How can I connect with ssl with the below properties

```
cassandra.ssl.enabled= cassandra.ssl.cipher.suites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA truststore.path= keystore.path= truststore.password= keystore.password=
```

Comment: Any help here please!!. We also need this kind of implementation, how to implement ssl_options using django_cassandra_engine